# single Xpath for multiple fields in odoo 8

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, odoo, odoo-8

I need to replace some fields,buttons and label in a view. Now i am using Xpath like below to achieve it.

```
 <xpath expr='//field[@name="use_timesheets"]' position="replace">  </xpath>
 <xpath expr='//button[@class="oe_inline oe_stat_button"]' position="replace"></xpath>
 <xpath expr="//field[@name = 'template_id']" position="replace"></xpath>
```

Is it possible to use single Xpath for multiple field like:

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name in ['template_id','name']" position="replace"></xpath>
```

Is it possible??

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in XPath 2.0 or above :

```
//field[@name=('template_id','name')]
```

And in XPath 1.0 using `or` operator :

```
//field[@name='template_id' or @name='name']
```

I'm not sure which XPath version is supported by odoo.

Comment: AFAIK v2 is not supported :(

Comment: Yes, `lxml` is used which supports XPath version 1.0.

Comment: thanks har07, the second solution works. but there is a problem. Only one field is hide other still visible. Like `template_id`is hide but `name` not. I need to hide bot same time.

Comment: Hi, it's a bit late but with the or, it will only take the first field matching the condition